# new Spring Starter Project - pom error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Every time I create a Spring Starter Project in Eclipse (Luna 4.4.2) with STS I get the following error:[image]

I tried Maven > Update Project and mvn clean install but i didn't work.
It's brand new project, I made no changes. What is going on?

Comment: Make sure, your company repository has access to the complete Maven central repository. You should contact your company administrators to clarify that.

Comment: repo.deere.com may not have access to central. If it does eventually (because someone as more rights to pull the libraries) you need to run maven with the `-U` flag to force a refresh of the meta-data.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `<relativePath/>` tag. It looks as though it is not checking the maven repository for the dependency, this could be because it thinks it is a local project due to the `<relativePath/>` tag.

Does it build from the command line if you do a `mvn package`?

Comment: Removing <relativePath/> didn't help. Maven build fails with the same message

Comment: Please try to run your project as maven test it give provide you actual error

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still facing the same error as of 2017, below is the solution.

I faced the same issue and manage to solve it by

deleting all maven local repo and update it back using maven -> update project